# How to make google spreadsheet public?

Tags: python, api, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

This program creates new google spreadsheet but I can't access it. How to make it public? I tried using google drive api but then I watched a video where dude didn't use it and everything was ok so I'm confused.

```
import httplib2
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def get_service_sacc():
    creds_json = "bubbly-mantis-357613-85d3b9e3b0f9.json"
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

    creds_service = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(creds_json, scopes).authorize(httplib2.Http())
    return build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds_service)

def init_spreadsheet(title):
    service = get_service_sacc()
    spreadsheet = {
        'properties': {
            'title': title,
        }
    }
    spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet,
                                            fields='spreadsheetId') \
    .execute()
    print(f"Spreadsheet ID: {(spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId'))}")
    return spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId')


init_spreadsheet("CRYPTO")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved by using google drive api

```
def get_creds():
    creds_json = "bubbly-mantis-357613-85d3b9e3b0f9.json"
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    creds_service = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(creds_json, scopes).authorize(httplib2.Http())

    return creds_service

def get_service_sacc():
    return build('sheets', 'v4', http=get_creds())

def init_spreadsheet(title):
    service = get_service_sacc()
    spreadsheet = {
        'properties': {
            'title': title,
        }
    }
    spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet,
                                            fields='spreadsheetId').execute()

    spreadsheetId = spreadsheet['spreadsheetId']

    driveService = googleapiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3',
                                         http=get_creds())
    access = driveService.permissions().create(
        fileId=spreadsheetId,
        body={'type': 'anyone', 'role': 'reader'},
        fields='id'
    ).execute()
    print(f"Spreadsheet ID: {(spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId'))}")
    return spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId')
```